# fs.watch is there an error handler if file does not exist?

Tags: javascript, node.js

in `nodejs` [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener) module.

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.watch('target.txt', function() {
console.log("File 'target.txt' just changed!");
});
```

if file does not exist I get:

```
fs.js:1172
    throw errnoException(err, 'watch');
          ^
Error: watch ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1172:11)
```

isn't there an `err` callback in case the file does not exist? what is the proper way to handle errors here?

Comment: which version of node are you using  ?

Comment: @amanpurohit v0.12.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to wrap it like this, it will check for file existing before doing any stuff.

```
    if (fs.existsSync('target.txt')) {
        fs.watch('target.txt', function() {
           console.log("File 'target.txt' just changed!");
        });
    }
```